# Sudoku code checker in c

Tags: c, sudoku

I'm writing a Sudoku solution checker for a class and I've hit a wall.

I'm at the point where I'm checking if I can see whether or individual columns and rows are unique. For some reason the code works on 4x4 grids but as soon as I get up to a 5x5 grid or higher (goal is to get to a 9x9 grid) the program starts to print out that it had failed even when it should succeed.

Any help would be much needed, I want need a point in the right direction or where I should look into

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i, j, n, k, p, q;
    int fail;
    int array[5][5];
    int check[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int a = 0;
    char *output = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    // memory allocated for yes or no at end
    output = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));

    while (a < n)
    {
        fail = 0;
        //  create this 2D array
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &(array[i][j]));
            }
        }

        // seeing if row is unique
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                if (array[i][k] == array[i][k+1])
                    fail += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // seeing if column is unique
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                if (array[k][j] == array[k+1][j])
                    fail += 1;
                }
            }
        }

       /* for (WHAT DO I DO FOR ROWS)
        {
            for (WHAT DO I DO FOR ROWS AGAIN BUT REPLACE ROWS WITH COLUMNS)
            {
                for (NOW IM LOST)
            }
        }

        */
        //  success or failure? 0 success, 1 failure
        if (fail >= 1)
            output[a] = 1;
        else
            output[a] = 0;

        a++;

        }

    // print out yah or nah

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (output[i] == 0)
                printf("YES\n");
            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }

  return 0;
}
```

Forget my for loop for the grids, I'll work on that once I figure out how to get the columns and rows working correctly.

Thanks for the help!

Here is an input that would cause the program to fail when it should succeed

```
1 
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

output would be

NO

EDIT: It is now working with a 9x9 grid! Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIDE_LENGTH 9

int main ()
{
    int i, j, n, k, p, q;
    int fail;
    int array[SIDE_LENGTH][SIDE_LENGTH];
    int check[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int a = 0;
    char *output = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    // memory allocated for yes or no at end
    output = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n));

    while (a < n)
    {
        fail = 0;
        //  create this 2D array
        for (i = 0; i < SIDE_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < SIDE_LENGTH; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &(array[i][j]));
            }
        }

        // seeing if row is unique
        for (i = 0; i < SIDE_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < SIDE_LENGTH; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < SIDE_LENGTH - 1; k++)
                {
                if (array[i][k] == array[i][k+1])
                    fail += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // seeing if column is unique
        for (i = 0; i < SIDE_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < SIDE_LENGTH; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < SIDE_LENGTH - 1; k++)
                {
                if (array[k][j] == array[k+1][j])
                    fail += 1;
                }
            }
        }

       /* for (WHAT DO I DO FOR ROWS)
        {
            for (WHAT DO I DO FOR ROWS AGAIN BUT REPLACE ROWS WITH COLUMNS)
            {
                for (NOW IM LOST)
            }
        }

        */
        //  success or failure? 0 success, 1 failure
        if (fail >= 1)
            output[a] = 1;
        else
            output[a] = 0;

        a++;

        }

    // print out yah or nah

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (output[i] == 0)
                printf("YES\n");
            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }

  return 0;
}
```

input:

```
1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: `array[i][k] == array[i][k+1]` um.. `k+1` ? That's out of range on the last iteration. And I hold the logic suspect regardless.

Comment: I have a strong feeling it's a problem with my logic here and I may instead try doing a for loop going with (k = 5; k > 0; k--) and then the array being array[i][k] == array[i][k-1]

Comment: [It is not clear what you are complaining about](http://ideone.com/NYVUqf). Show an input where it fails.

Comment: @JoeyOhannesian  Let the loop go till `k<4` .

Comment: Changing my logic made it so 5x5 arrays work! But 6x6 arrays don't work surprisingly

Comment: My output shows that it fails for any grid greater than 4x4 when it should succeed, I think it has to do with my logic but I have no idea where it's going wrong. I'll try out amey's suggestion

Comment: You need to show your exact program and an input on which it fails.

Comment: @ameyCU's suggestion fixed the problem that was occurring. I'm guessing the problem lied with the fact that I was trying to access a memory address that hadn't been created or something along those lines. I'll edit my post to show an input that would fail

Comment: @JoeyOhannesian  Yes please show inputs and result .

Comment: That cannot be the only input. you're eating the first `int` with that initial `scanf`.

Comment: Oh... silly me. I'll edit it, I put 1 for the initial int because I've tested the while loop early on so I know it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the comparison.

```
if (array[i][k] == array[i][k+1])
```

I think you are using i as row and column index, then using j to iterate for duplicates.  k will be what you compare against so ...

```
/* compare if j'th value is same as k'th value */ 
if (j != k && array[i][j] == array[i][k]) /* Don't check same against same */
```

the second comparison should be

```
 /* compare if j'th value is same as k'th value */ 
if (j != k && array[j][i] == array[k][i]) /* Don't check same against same */
```

That would fix your overflow (k+1) bug, and get you going.
The squares could be fixed with

```
struct co_ords {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct co_ords boxes[][9] = {{ {0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2},
                               {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2},
                               {2,0}, {2,1}, {2,2} 
                             },
                             { {3,0}, {3,1}, {3,2},
                               {4,0}, {4,1}, {4,2},
                               {5,0}, {5,1}, {5,2} },
... /* more boxes go here */
                             { {6,6}, {6,7}, {6,8},
                               {7,6}, {7,7}, {7,8},
                               {8,6}, {8,7}, {8,8} }};


for( i = 0; i < 9; i++ ){
  struct co_ords current_box * = boxes[i];
  for( j = 0; j < 9; j++ ) {
     for( k = 0; k < 9; k++ ){
        if( j != k && array[ current_box[j].x ][ current_box[j].y] == array[ current_box[k].x ][ current_box[k].y] )
           fail += 1;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ameyCU helped find the error in my code

Setting k to one less than what i and j were set to allowed the code to successfully run on any X*X sized grid. Because k is one less than i and j, it won't try to access a part of the array that hasn't been allocated yet which is where my problem lied.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
      for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
      {
        if (array[i][k] == array[i][k+1])
        fail += 1;
      }
    }
 }
```

Despite the overwriting of the array as already pointed out, your logic is flawed. You don't use `j` at all. You are just comparing the same values five times.

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[5][5];
```

so the array is allocated as 5x5

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &(array[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

and you are indexing from 0 to 5 ..

to use larger, please do replace all those "5"s with a precompiler definition.

```
#define SUDOKU_SIDE_LENGTH 5
```

...

```
int array[SUDOKU_SIDE_LENGTH ][SUDOKU_SIDE_LENGTH ];
```

...

```
    for (i = 0; i < SUDOKU_SIDE_LENGTH ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SUDOKU_SIDE_LENGTH ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &(array[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

etc.. that will ensure that you always allocate enough space for the array.

adjust size on the definition, not in the code..

Comment: the precompiler replaces the defined macro, with a value: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx`before compiling

Comment: (to but not including)

Comment: That should be fine .

Comment: I completely forgot I could do this, I'll incorporate it in!

Comment: No, he's indexing 0 to 4 in those loops, there's no access to index 5...

Comment: @LeonardoLourenço  He edited the code in question. Please take a look .

Comment: @ameyCU I just reloaded the page and it's still written for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){ for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) both fors does not execute when the variable reaches 5, so it can't index 5...

Comment: @LeonardoLourenço  And they should no go to index `5` else it will be **UB** for accessing memory out of bounds . Remember `0 to 4` is `5 elements` .

Comment: @JoeyOhannesian revised code doesn't invalidate my comment.

Comment: @ameyCU He said "and you are indexing from 0 to 5" since both fors doesn't execute for value 5, there's no indexing 5, just 0 to 4...

Comment: @LeonardoLourenço  Yes I took that point too previously . But see his 2 nd comment . He said not including `5` .

Comment: this is all a matter of how you define "to" .. stop arguing, and go to this fiddle for any concerns regarding indexing.. http://fiddle.jshell.net/t46hvLj1/